# Add averages to column for each group in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I have a table which contains a list of repeated names, a score value, and a score type. How can I group by name, get the average of score value for each name for each score type, and add this average to a float column I've created called avg_score? Example:

```
NAME        SCORE_TYPE       SCORE_VALUE     AVG_SCORE << Desired Output

bob         base_score       5               4
bob         base_score       4               4 
bob         base_score       3               4
bob         revised_score    1               3
bob         revised_score    5               3
bob         revised_score    3               3 
jack        base_score       5               5
jack        base_score       7               5 
jack        base_score       3               5
jack        revised_score    1               1
jack        revised_score    1               1
jack        revised_score    1               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add this to a table, you need `update`:

```
update t
    set AVG_SCORE = tt.avg_score
    from (select name, score_type, avg(score) as avg_score
          from t
          group by name, score_type
         ) tt
    where tt.name = t.name and tt.score_type = t.score_type;
```

Answer (score 1):

use window function

```
select *, 
avg(SCORE_VALUE) over(partition by NAME,SCORE_TYPE) as AVG_SCORE from t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
name
,score_type
,score_value
,avg(score_value) over(partition by name,score_type) as AVG_SCORE
from [table name]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.